# When to resend data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, network-programming

I'm writing an app that sends and receives data to and from a server.

It is important that the data gets sent to the server so I'm tracking what has and what hasn't been sent.

Download data is not so important but upload is.

Anyway, it is possible that the upload will fail (if there is no internet connection, etc...) and so I'm marking these records so that I know they haven't sent up to the server yet.

My question is... When should I be resending this data?

I don't really want a timer as it seems like overkill. Should I set a watch on network connectivity and send anything remaining when the network comes back? But then I'll miss it if the connectivity changed while the app wasn't running.

Maybe I should just look for anything unsent when the users sends something new?

Comment: Assuming that you found a way to resolve data conflicts for a user that has two phones, you can still check connectivity in the app delegate when the app wakes up from background, and send (or not) a notification to send more data. Also, since upload is critical, you might want to bracket it into a background task.

Comment: Ah, good idea thanks. I already have all the upload stuff running in the background and it's all managed by a class with an NSOperationQueue. Checking connectivity on wake up is a brilliant idea though. Thanks.

Comment: Checking connectivity is an extra step. You could simply send the data with a NSURLConnection and you'll get a reply if it succeeded or failed.

Comment: I think my question has been confused. I'm asking when I should REsend it after it has failed once. I've used @Alex advice anyway now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In My thought:

1. You need to check the network status each time when you sent the data.
2. Also keep an eye on the connection while sending data
3. If the data is successfully uploaded, sent an acknowledgement from the server to client, So that you can ensure the data successfully uploaded.